# Why UML diagrams not showing up in eclipse juno with UML2 tools. Rather it shows xml content

Tags: uml

I have installed UML2 tools. When I try to open up UML files with extension '.umlclass', it shows up xml content. Am expecting proper UML diagrams to be shown in the editor. Please advise what else needs to be done to see UML diagrams in eclipse. Sample xml content as below.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Eclipse Model Development Tools (MDT) with "UML2 tools" you do not have any editor installed. So, for showing any diagrams you will need to install a full product first.
Additionally .uml ist the default extension for Eclipse UML2 files. You need to ask yourself where you got those .umlclass files from and which tool created them. Do they contain uml2 xmi? If yes you can probably rename them to .uml.